# How to use Fuseki for storing data persistently with ontology schema

Tags: jena, ontology, fuseki

Hi I'm new to ontology storing :)

Actually I'm looking for a triplestore with Java interoperability (Jena). So I choose Apache Fuseki.
In the documentation I found the ja:MemoryModel for loading ontologies. But does this mean the data is lost when I shut down the server?

Another idea is to use some kind of ontology schema. This means I want to use 1 ontology as schema and a second one for storing the entities. In  the example configuration.ttl I found something like that:

```
ja:baseModel 
[ a ja:MemoryModel ;
  ja:content [ja:externalContent <file:Data/test_abox.ttl>] ;
  ja:content [ja:externalContent <file:Data/test_tbox.ttl>] ;
] ;
```

But I couldn’t found a real explanation for the baseModel and in the documentation there is also the OntModel mentioned. Which one to use for schema and which one for entities. For me as newcomer it’s a little bit confusing? 
Could someone be so kind as to give me a hint for that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can run the server with a persistent database.  Start the server with --loc=DB and it will use it's copy of Jena TDB as the datastore.

Or you can use the assembler and configure in a TDB-backed datastore and a model from that.